# Работа 3/4G-модема отличие от смартфонов

Tags: android, сеть, 3g

Работа 3G/4G-модема идет по такому же принципу как и современные смартфоны?
Идентификаторы такие же или отличаются? Тот же IMEI, IMSI например...

В чем принципиальное отличие смартфонов и 3\4G модемов, в плане работы(Идентификаторы,Идентификации) скажем так.

Только начинаю учится... разбираться. Просьба, быть вежливым.

Comment: В общих чертах да, но есть и некоторые отличия в настройках, которые сотовые операторы могут зловредно отлавливать и не давать вам раздавать интернет через модем (а через смартфон всё ок раздаётся при этом).

Comment: В плане работы непосредственно модема, никакого принципиального отличия нет. Технически и в смартфоне, и в свистке может быть один и тот же чип. Если речь идёт о том, как операторы их различают - то есть несколько известных способов (IMEI, анализ трафика), возможно есть ещё хитрости, но на то они и хитрости - операторы о них не рассказывают.

Comment: Из хитростей только TTL и IMEI не телефонный. Какая-то там ещё хитрость была от МТС, но опять же связанная с TTL, чуть более замороченный способ, где фиксация не работает, а приходится его вычислять. Также трафик смотрят, если по трафику идёт обновление windows, то глушат скорость. Изучайте темы по [модемам](https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showtopic=582284) и про [обходы блокировок](https://4pda.to/forum/index.php?showtopic=689378), **4PDA** кладезь знаний на эту тему.

Comment: А, ну и забавный факт, на большинстве модемов от huawei сидит урезанный android.

Comment: @DiMithras Во, точно, `TTL` там другой был

Comment: @CrazyElf небольшое уточнение. Помимо того, что он другой, при раздаче он ещё инкрементируется. Т.е. раздачу можно скрыть как на телефоне, так и на модеме, для тарифов с платной ограниченной раздачей. Но, как говорится, на свой страх и риск. Возможно в договоре на тарифный план предусмотрены пункты, по которым могут снять с тарифа.